# How to pass an attribute to XML message in SOAP webservice callout

Tags: apex, callout, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I have a WSDL that I have imported in Salesforce and parsed using the WSDL2APEX option . It generates a sample message like below.

```
    <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <MaterialNumber>1938449</MaterialNumber>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <MaterialNumber>BJ15210</MaterialNumber>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
```

However I need to pass an attribute for the total count of the line items.

```
    <LineItems count="2">
        <LineItem>
            <MaterialNumber>1938449</MaterialNumber>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <MaterialNumber>BJ15210</MaterialNumber>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
```

Any help to achieve this is highly appreciated. Looking for guidance on how to modify the generated apex classes.

edit sample Apex class generated from the WSDL:

```
public class TestWsClass {
    public class Header{
        public String BatchID;        
        public TestWsClass.ArrayOfLineItem LineItems;
        private String[] BankBatchID_type_info = new String[]{'BankBatchID','http://Soap30/message/',null,'0','1','false'};        
        private String[] LineItems_type_info = new String[]{'LineItems','http://Soap30/message/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://Soap30/message/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'BatchID','LineItems'};        

    public class LineItem {
        public String MaterialNumber;
        private String[] MaterialNumber_type_info = new String[]{'MaterialNumber','http://Soap30/message/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://Soap30/message/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'MaterialNumber'};
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to add some extra value in XML you got and sent as response in the callout?

Comment: Yes correct. The apex classes that are generated by importing the WSDl don't have any way for me to pass in the attribute "count" to add it to the outgoing xml message

Comment: Can you post the generated apex?  Then we may be able to show you where to add the code

Comment: @willard added the sample apex code that's generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of wsdl2apex. Or more specifically, `WebServiceCallout.invoke` that the generated code is ultimately used with.

As you can see, the generation of an XML element in the SOAP message requires two parts in the parent class:

1. The member to contain the actual data.
   `public TestWsClass.ArrayOfLineItem LineItems;`
2. A corresponding `*_type_info` that contains the metadata required to generate the correct XML Element.
   `private String[] LineItems_type_info = new String[]{'LineItems','http://Soap30/message/',null,'0','1','false'};`

They are linked by a naming convention that the latter is a suffix on the members name.

XML attributes follow the same pattern, except rather than using `*_type_info` they use `*__att_info`.
In your case it would look something like:

```
public class ArrayOfLineItem {
    // ... Existing class body
    public String count;
    private String[] count_att_info = new String[]{'count'};
}
```

See also:

- [Issue with SOAP Header created via Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179121/102)
- [What are the parameters for the Salesforce WebServiceCallout.invoke method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4392616/54026)